# BAC - CAB Special Case

Tags: cross-product

Let vectors $\vec A, \vec B$ represent the sides of a quadrilateral parallelogram.

$\vec B \times (\vec A \times \vec B) $

$= \vec A(\vec B \cdot \vec B) - \vec B(\vec B \cdot \vec A)$

$= B^2 \vec A - \vec B(\vec B \cdot \vec A)$

Is the last line typed above the simplest way to express the triple cross product when two of the three vectors are the same?

Or can I simplify it to:

$= B^2 \vec A - (\vec B \vec B \cdot \vec B \vec A)$

Please point me in the right direction. I could not find this "vector property" aka:

vector times ( vector dot vector)

anywhere online.

Comment: What does ${\vec A}{\vec B}$ mean?

Comment: Thank you for catching the duplicate line.

Comment: You want to replace $B(B\cdot A)$ with what, $B^2\cdot BA$? What does this mean? $B^2$ is a scalar, so the $\cdot$ means scalar multiplication, then $BA$ means...?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Your comment made me realize my dot product did not make sense. Could I distribute it as I did above(after the word "simplify")?

Comment: Now you have ${\vec B}{\vec B}\cdot{\vec B}{\vec A}$... but you didn't answer our question: **what do you mean when you write two vectors next to each other**? As in ${\vec B}{\vec A}$, what do you think that means?

Comment: I also don't understand the new version. But here's one thing you can try; if the identity is true for $B$, then it is also true if you replace $B$ everywhere with $2B$. Thus the total number of $B$s in any one product (however you define a product, which must certainly be bilinear) must be the same.

Comment: @runway44 It is a matrix transformation. I am asking if I am breaking any rules for math distributing it this way.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I do not understand what you mean by bilinear or how could say vector B times vector B = 2B

Comment: If you view $\vec{B}$ as a column vector, then you can write ${\vec B}({\vec B}\cdot{\vec A})$ as ${\vec B}{\vec B}^T{\vec A}$. Notice the **transpose** is necessary for this to make sense as matrix multiplication - without the transpose the dimensions don't match and you can't do the matrix multiplication.

Comment: @runway44 You're right!! I misinterpreted what a transformation matrix looks like. Thank you for clarifying. It looks as if it cannot be simplified pass the equation line.

Comment: No, I'm saying if you want e.g. $B( B\cdot A) = BBBA$ to be true for all vectors $B$, whatever the meaning of $BBBA$, as long as the product is linear in each factor, then it is also true that $4 (B\cdot A) = (2B)( (2B)\cdot A) = (2B)(2B)(2B)A = 8 BBBA$, which means your guess is wrong

Comment: It is because you are claiming an identity for all vectors $B$. So you can put anything for $B$. Like $B=2C$, for some other vector $C$. I just used the same letter $B$ instead of $C$. If you don't get it then it seems your problem is solved anyway so nevermind

Comment: @CalvinKhor I see what you are saying. I am creating an identity out of nothing. Also, I realized that (A x B) creates a vector that is perpendicular to A and B. Hence A x ( B x A) = 1.

Comment: If $B = (k,0,0)$ and $A=(0,k,0)$ then $ B\times A=(0,0,k^2)$ and then $A\times (B\times A) = (-k^3, 0 ,0)$ which is not 1 (or (1,1,1), or (1,0,0), or (0,1,0), or however you want to interpret the symbol "1")

Comment: @CalvinKhor There I go assuming again. Thank you for that mini proof. I guess as simplified as it could be due to the "BAC - CAB" rule for triple cross products. Thank you Calvin